# Journey Builder: 1 email related to 2 subscriber keys

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

is it possible for Journey Builder to send 2 emails to one email address if 2 subscriber keys (in our case, Contact_Keys) are different but have the same email adress value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is very simple: Yes.

Actually, this is one of the use cases where using a SubscriberKey is important. Allowing multiple contacts to have the same email address while treated as different persons by Marketing Cloud.

Comment: Ok. And as a follow-up question, can we deactivate the " de-duplicate on email address" option which is set as default in Journey Builder, but can be switched off in guided email sends?

Comment: I don't believe there is a de-duplicate on email address option on email in Journey Buider. The only way to deduplicate emails in Journey Builder if you are not using EmailAddress as Primary key is through SQL. There is an idea that you can upvote https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000PZHmQAO.